# Text Disappearing When Window Opens

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, resize, window

So, I have a form for a sign up, and in the design, it looks like this:

[image: What the sign up is supposed to look like]

And here's the XAML for that:

```
<Rectangle x:Name="signInBox" Fill="#FF5F5F6E" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="450" Margin="0,0,0,0" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="640" StrokeThickness="3" Visibility="Visible"/>
<TextBlock x:Name="signUpText" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,-350,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Sign up for Horizon Chat" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontFamily="Muli" FontSize="36" Foreground="White"/>
<!-- For the username box -->
<TextBox x:Name="nameSignUpBox" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,-150,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="370" FontFamily="Muli" FontSize="26" BorderThickness="2" MaxHeight="61" MaxWidth="686"/>
<TextBlock x:Name="nameSignUpBoxDescription" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="456,334,738,544" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Username" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontFamily="Muli" FontSize="18" Foreground="#FFDADADA"/>
<!-- For the email box -->
<TextBox x:Name="emailSignUpBox" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="370" FontFamily="Muli" FontSize="26" BorderThickness="2" MaxHeight="61" MaxWidth="686"/>
<TextBlock x:Name="emailSignUpBoxDescription" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="456,408,778,468" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Email" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontFamily="Muli" FontSize="18" Foreground="#FFDADADA"/>
<!-- For the password box -->
<PasswordBox x:Name="passwordSignUpBox" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,150,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="370" FontFamily="Muli" FontSize="26" BorderThickness="2" MaxHeight="61" MaxWidth="686"/>
<TextBlock x:Name="passwordSignUpBoxDescription" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="455,484,742,393" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Password" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontFamily="Muli" FontSize="18" Foreground="#FFDADADA"/>
```

Then, when the program starts, it undergoes some changes, like changing the window size to fit that box, and making that visible, and all that. Here's the code for that:

```
BrushConverter brushconverter = new BrushConverter();
this.Background = (Brush)brushconverter.ConvertFrom("#FF9C9C9C");
this.Width = 640;
this.Height = 450;
this.ResizeMode = ResizeMode.NoResize;
double screenWidth = System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth;
double screenHeight = System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight;
double windowWidth = this.Width;
double windowHeight = this.Height;
this.Left = (screenWidth / 2) - (windowWidth / 2);
this.Top = (screenHeight / 2) - (windowHeight / 2);
```

Now, all that just has to do with the window, because in my case, I already have all the stuff visible. So, when I do launch the program, I get everything *except* the small text above the boxes (Username, Email, and Password). Here's that:

[image: What the window ends up as]

Now, my guess is that it moves the text somewhere during the resize, since when I don't resize the window, it's still there (like in the designer). However, it is still a problem if it is moving my text to a different place. How can I fix this?

**EDIT:** I tried to resize the designer window, and here's the before and after of resizing it about 100px:

Before:

[image: Before]

50%:

[image: 50%]

And after:

[image: After]

Comment: You really shouldn't be using margins to place text, if you need to do that, use a Canvas instead of a Grid. However what you really should be doing is correctly laying out your labels/textboxes in the grid using rows/columns that will resize without the code-behind.

Comment: @RonBeyer What's the disadvantage of using margins on text?

Comment: Exactly what you are experiencing! WPF is made to be "resolution independent", what you are trying to do is use pixel offsets and then scale them, basically shoehorning WinForms practices into WPF. If you set up your grid correctly, and place text in the right spots, you don't have to worry about code-behind to scale the form, WPF does it for you.

Comment: If you are too lazy to redesign your XAML, there's a one line fix for your problem despite being a bad practice for such kind of things - put everything inside a ViewBox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using @shadow32 I re-organized the controls into a viewbox and created a purely xaml solution for your dynamic sizing requirement.
I also cleaned up the XAML, less is more heh.
Hopefully you can use this approach, try to keep the layout in the designer if at possible. 
It makes for a more maintainable solution.

```
    <Window x:Class="WpfApp1.Window1"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
            xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
            xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
            mc:Ignorable="d"
            Title="Window1" Height="450" Width="800">
        <Window.Resources>
            <!--SET THE TEXT STYLING, AVOID REPEATING THE SAME STYLE-->
            <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Muli" />
                <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="Wrap" />
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FFDADADA"/>
                <!--MARGIN SPACES OUT THE DATA ENTRY FIELDS-->
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,5,0,0"></Setter>
            </Style>
        </Window.Resources>
        <!--ROOT CONTAINER CONTROL WITH MARGIN TO CENTER-->
        <DockPanel Margin="50,0" >

            <!--SIDE BORDER AND BACKGROUND-->
            <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1,0" Background="#FF5F5F6E">

                <!--VIEWBOX FOR SCALING-->
                <Viewbox VerticalAlignment="Top">

                    <!--DOCK PANEL FOR WRAPPING HEADER AND DATA ENTRY CONTROLS-->
                    <DockPanel >

                        <!--HEADER WITH MARGIN TO PAD THE TOP-->
                        <TextBlock x:Name="signUpText"
                                   Text="Sign up for Horizon Chat"
                                   Foreground="White"
                                   Margin="0,10,0,0" 
                                   DockPanel.Dock="Top"
                                   FontSize="20"/>

                        <!--STACKPANEL FOR ORDERING CONTROLS-->
                        <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Margin="5,0">

                            <!--TOP PADDING TEXTBLOCK-->
                            <TextBlock />

                            <!-- For the username box -->
                            <TextBlock x:Name="nameSignUpBoxDescription" 
                                       Text="Username" />
                            <TextBox x:Name="nameSignUpBox" />

                            <!-- For the email box -->
                            <TextBlock x:Name="emailSignUpBoxDescription" 
                                       Text="Email" />
                            <TextBox x:Name="emailSignUpBox" />

                            <!-- For the password box -->
                            <TextBlock x:Name="passwordSignUpBoxDescription" 
                                       Text="Password" />
                            <PasswordBox x:Name="passwordSignUpBox" />

                            <!--BOTTOM PADDING TEXTBLOCK-->
                            <TextBlock />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DockPanel>
                </Viewbox>
            </Border>
        </DockPanel>
    </Window>
```